AWS Chatbot does not send a message to Slack when AWS Budget comes back to OK status
I configured an alert using AWS Chatbot/SNS/Budget when forecasted costs surpass a value. Chatbot sends a message to a Slack channel.
It works, but when the budget returns to OK status, Chatbot does not send any message. What can I do?
